# Element contains not working (Angular 2+, RxJS)

Tags: angular, typescript, dom, rxjs

Here is my code. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tq2vaa

```
constructor(private host: ElementRef) {
}

get element() {
    return this.host.nativeElement;
}

private editModeHandler() {
     const clickOutside$ = fromEvent(document, 'click').pipe(
        filter(({ target }) => {
        console.log('parent', this.element, 'child', target)

          const ans = this.element.contains(target) === false
          console.log(ans)
          return  ans
        }),
        take(1)
     )
}
```

This is what it prints in the console. As you can see, app-editable-component contains h3 which is the target but why ans is true???

[image: cont]

Comment: What is `this.element` here?

Comment: this.element is returning this.host.nativeElement;

Comment: And what's this.host?

Comment: constructor(private host: ElementRef) {
  }

Comment: Something like testing for whether a click was outside of an element is probably best done using a directive, for reusability. See http://willtaylor.blog/click-outside-directive/

Comment: @SiddAjmera Sorry wrong link here is the correct link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iah7up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to test your code, see [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tq2vaa?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

```js
import { Component, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import  {fromEvent } from 'rxjs';
import { filter, take } from 'rxjs/operators';


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {

constructor(private host: ElementRef) {
  this.editModeHandler();
}

get element() {
    return this.host.nativeElement;
}

private editModeHandler() {
      fromEvent(document, 'click')
      .pipe(
        filter(({ target }) => {
        console.log('parent', this.element, 'child', target)

          const ans = this.element.contains(target) === false
          console.log(ans)
          return  ans
        }),
        take(1)
     ).subscribe();
}  

}
```

when i click on the `<h3>` tag `ans` shows `false` ! am i doing the same thing as you ? am i missing something ?

[image]

**UPDATE** .

After your stackblitz i see what's happening. I'll try to be simple :

1. You click on the `h3` element
2. `edit` mode is activated (so the `h3` is replaced by the `input`)
3. The click event is catched by the `document` because click is bubbling and the `contains(h3)` will return `false` (because of #2)
4. `switchMapTo(clickOutside$)` is executed
5. `view` mode is activated (really speed, so you'll not see the input appearing ans disappearing).

To fix it, you can stop the propagation when its catched by the host element.

```js
private viewModeHandler() {
        fromEvent(this.element, 'click').pipe(
            untilDestroyed(this)
        ).subscribe((e) => {
            console.log('clicked inside');
            this.editMode.next(true);
            this.mode = 'edit';
            e.stopPropagation();
        });
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It works in App component but if you put the same code in another component it does what I described in the question check the code on stackblitz here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tq2vaa

Comment: your stackblitz is as mine !

Comment: Thank you so much! I have upvoted! You saved me I spent +8 hours on this :) I would never guess that